# How to build OData service which doesn't saves result in variables to reduce fetch time from second time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, soap, odata

I have developed an OData Service which fetches 50000 records from one table present in Database. My purpose is to **check & compare the response time of an OData service with SOAP webservice**. Same service has been developed in SOAP also.

OData service is built without using EntityFramework in .NET.

Now my observation is that SOAP takes same time in all the requests. But the OData service takes more time than SOAP only during the first call. Subsequent calls are comparatively faster.

When I debugged the code I found that OData service is hitting the database for the first time only. Subsequent requests are fulfilled by passing data from that saved variables.  Since my table is a transaction table, the values can change rapidly, thereby giving possibly incorrect results.

Code -:

**Entity class -:**

```
namespace Demo.Models
{
    public class EBAN
    {
        [Key]
        public String MANDT { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public String BANFN { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public String BNFPO { get; set; }

        public String BSART { get; set; }
        public String BSTYP { get; set; }
        public String BSAKZ { get; set; }
        public String LOEKZ { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Data Fetching -:**

```
using Demo.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OracleClient;

    namespace Demo.DataSource
    {
        public class DemoDataSources
        {

            private static DemoDataSources instance = null;
            public int noOfRecords { get; set; }
            public static DemoDataSources Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new DemoDataSources();
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
            }
            public List<EBAN> EBAN { get; set; }
            private DemoDataSources()
            {
                this.Reset();
                this.Initialize();
            }
            public void Reset()
            {
                this.EBAN = new List<EBAN>();
            }
            public void Initialize()
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "     Select MANDT,     BANFN,     BNFPO, BSART, bstyp , BSAKZ, LOEKZ      from ctdrdb.t_eban_mm WHERE rownum < = 5";

                dt = getDataTableWithParams(cmd);


                List<EBAN> l = new List<EBAN>();
                EBAN e;

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    e = new EBAN()
                    {
                        MANDT = dt.Rows[i]["MANDT"].ToString(),
                        BANFN = dt.Rows[i]["BANFN"].ToString(),
                        BNFPO = dt.Rows[i]["BNFPO"].ToString(),
                        BSART = dt.Rows[i]["BSART"].ToString(),
                        BSTYP = dt.Rows[i]["bstyp"].ToString(),
                        BSAKZ = dt.Rows[i]["BSAKZ"].ToString(),
                        LOEKZ = dt.Rows[i]["LOEKZ"].ToString(),

                    };
                    l.Add(e);
                }


                this.EBAN.AddRange(l);


            }

            public DataTable getDataTableWithParams(OracleCommand Orcmd)
            {
                OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConnGetSmsDetail);
                try
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    OracleDataAdapter da;

                    //OPENING THE CONNECTION
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    { conn.Open(); }

                    Orcmd.Connection = conn;
                    da = new OracleDataAdapter(Orcmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    da.Dispose();
                    //CLOSING THE CONNECTION
                    conn.Close();
                    return dt;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

        }   

    }
```

**Controller Class -:**

```
 [EnableQuery]
        public class EBANController : ApiController
        {     
            public IHttpActionResult Get()
            {
               return Ok(DemoDataSources.Instance.EBAN.AsQueryable());
            }  

        }
```

***How do I hit the Database always rather than storing in variables (as is the case in SOAP service) and also reduce the response time*** as is claimed by an OData service. Also how to do the same using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are causing this yourself. You're returning the same DemoDataSources.Instance.EBAN each time.

Comment: Can you pin point the exact mistake in the code? And also how do I change the code to take less time than SOAP service.I can see the difference in file size ( which is because JSON file will always be of lesser size than XML file)